# What is the best way to implement a circular array byte shift in java?

Tags: java, arrays, bit-shift

If the shifting is not always the same, i.e I may have to use the same function to resize 2 or 4 characters, what would be a good way to circular shift the values of an array of bytes 2 positions * a parameter? This is what I have so far

```
for(int j=0; j<param; j++){
        if(j == 0){
            for(int i=0; i<myArray.length;i++){
                result[i] = (byte) (myArray[i]<<2); 
            }
        } else{
            for(int i=0; i<result.length;i++){
                if((result.length-i) > 2){
                    result[i] = (byte) (result[i]<<2);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Summing up, I have to circular shift the values of myArray twice times param and return the result in the array 'result'. I don't get how to do this when the parameter 'param' is not fixed.

Comment: There is a problem with your code. The condition "if(param == 0)" can never be met, as j can never be < 0.

Comment: Damn, I meant j instead of param. I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

First: If possible, use java.util.BitSet for tasks like that.

I am not sure, but somehow BitSet itself does not have shift, but [this source](http://www.exists.de/content/download/files/BitShuffler.java) looks it implemented it.

Comment: Why is Bitset better than using standard byte[] arrays?